# Having a label fade out in kivy

Tags: python, label, kivy, fadeout

So I want to display a label if someone tries to click play and there is no save file made yet. Then I want it to fade out. The while loop works, reducing the value of alpha to 0. And it displays the label as long as I don't have the `self.remove_widget(no_save)` added in but then it just stays as a solid label. Any help would be appreciated. Or is there an easier way to do this?

```
class StartMenu(Screen):

    def check_save(self):
        global save_state
        if save_state == None:
            color = (0,1,0,1)
            while color[3] > 0:
                no_save = Label(text='No save file found. Please press New Game', color=color)
                self.add_widget(no_save)
                color = color [:3] + (color[3] - (.1),)
                time.sleep(.1)
                self.remove_widget(no_save)
```

Comment: the `while` loop together with `sleep` is blocking your app and a very bad idea. Instead, have a look at [`Animation`s](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.animation.html)

Comment: Okay I will! I haven't heard of them yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than doing the fade out yourself, why not use the built in `Animation` functionality? Try something like this. I would also suggest moving `save_state` from the global realm to your class, and instead of creating and destroying the label every run, I would create at initialization and simply hide or show it as it becomes necessary.

```
class StartMenu(Screen):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.save_state = None
    no_save = Label('No save file found. Please press new game.', hidden=True)
    self.add_widget(no_save)


  def check_save(self):
    if not self.save_state:
       self.no_save.hidden = False
       def hide_label(w): w.hidden = True
       Animation(opacity=0, duration=1, on_complete=hide_label).start(self.no_save)
```

Quick shoutout to zeeMonkeys for pointing out the `Animation` solution in the comments before I did.

Comment: Thank you I found the animation page as suggested by zeeMonkeez and got it working. I do have a question about the global though. I need to access the save state information in the main game loop so would it be proper to use the global then. (I have the code so that if there is a save state found it loads it to the variable and I need to access that information elsewhere, is there a better way to do it)

Comment: @Arkyris, there are multiple ways to share data across widgets. One way would be to simply access the `save_state` property in your `MainScreen` widget (or whatever your main game loop function is in) as an attribute of `StartMenu`. (i.e., in the `__init__` of `MainScreen`, put `self.start_menu = StartMenu(...)`, and in your main game loop, use `self.start_menu.save_state`.) On the other hand, if you don't think that keeping `save_state` as an attribute is worth it, you can just use a global variable. I only changed it in my answer because global variables are usually considered bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I had heard globals were considered bad practice but I'm still new to programming so I was unaware of the method you described. I will use it though now that I know about it. I was also wondering about the making game loop, should I make it it's own class or add it to screen that people play the game from. What is considered best practice?

Comment: @Arkyris, whether to include the game logic in the screen or in a separate class is primarily a matter of preference, and often depends heavily on the application. I personally am I big fan of separation of logic and interface, but in certain situations, it can needlessly complicate things. I suggest you play around with both options and get a feel for which one you prefer.

Comment: Thank you Kwarrtz. I will see which will work best for me